# Force Octopus Deploy step to fail if PostDeploy Powershell script fails

Tags: octopus-deploy

In one of my Octopus Deploy steps, I have a Powershell script called `PostDeploy.ps1` that runs correctly, except that if it encounters an exception, the deployment continues as though it succeeded.

I've seen a few posts about the problems of powershell exit codes, but I can't find a solution for the particular problems of PostDeploy scripts.

How can I force a step to be marked as failed if PostDeploy encounters an error?

Comment: I've marked the answer by Alex M as correct because it addressed my question, but the actual cause of the issue was that PowerShell runs windows executables in a fire-and-forget fashion.  To pick up failure, I had to add `| Out-Host` on the executable call, and then do an if-check on `$LastExitCode -ne 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to fail with a combination of `$LastExitCode` is non-zero and `Exit 1`.

Couple googled up links:

- http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/7604-deploy-wont-fail-when-powershell-script-fails
- http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/4539-need-to-mark-a-step-as-failed
- http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/problems/18419-octopus-powershell-step-doesnt-display-error

P.S. I'm sure you aware, but just a reminder that a release in Octopus is snapshotting the version of variables, scripts, packages, etc. So would need to create a new release and/or packages.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code

```
$exePath=$OctopusParameters["Octopus.Action[mydeploystep].Output.Package.InstallationDirectoryPath"] + "\myapp.exe"
& $exePath
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)
{
    EXIT 1
}
```

Comment: `Octopus.Action[mydeploystep].` should be `Octopus.ActionDeployStepName.` or `Octopus.Action[DeployStepName].` ?